How to apply predefined stylistic rules?
This is my eslint configuration:
import js from '@eslint/js'
import globals from 'globals'
import reactHooks from 'eslint-plugin-react-hooks'
import reactRefresh from 'eslint-plugin-react-refresh'
import tseslint from 'typescript-eslint'
import stylistic from '@stylistic/eslint-plugin'

export default tseslint.config(
  { ignores: ['dist'] },
  {
    extends: [js.configs.recommended, ...tseslint.configs.recommended, stylistic.configs['recommended-flat'],],
    files: ['**/*.{ts,tsx}'],
    languageOptions: {
      ecmaVersion: 2020,
      globals: globals.browser,
    },
    plugins: {
      'react-hooks': reactHooks,
      'react-refresh': reactRefresh,
      '@stylistic': stylistic
    },
    rules: {
      ...reactHooks.configs.recommended.rules,
      'react-refresh/only-export-components': [
        'warn',
        { allowConstantExport: true },
      ],
      '@stylistic/indent': ['error', 2],  
    },
  },
)

But I still don't see issues like this fixed (see extra spaces). I tried many different things but I could not find a way to apply things like prettier does. I want something close to what prettier offers.
<div>
  <Button>        Click me</Button>
</div>

